# How to change the colors on the TradingView Advanced Real-Time Chart Widget indicators

Tags: trading, tradingview-api

I'm trying to override the default configuration on the [Advanced Real-Time Chart TradingView Widget](https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/).

I added a simple moving average on which I managed to set the period (from default 9 to 200).

I would like to change the color, but I didn't find any documentation on how to achieve that?

Question 1 : Is there any documentation on how to customize the widget?
Question 2 : Is it possible / how to change the indicators colors?

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to achieve:

```html
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
        <div id="tradingview_f7f00"></div>
        <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            new TradingView.widget(
                {
                    "width": 980,
                    "height": 610,
                    "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
                    "interval": "D",
                    "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
                    "theme": "light",
                    "style": "1",
                    "locale": "en",
                    "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
                    "enable_publishing": false,
                    "allow_symbol_change": true,
                    // ==================== BEGIN ====================
                    "studies": [
                        {
                            id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies",
                            // This sets the period
                            inputs: {
                                length: 200,
                            },
                            // This doesn't work...
                            styles: {
                                color: '#ff0000',
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                    // ====================  END  ====================
                    "container_id": "tradingview_f7f00"
                }
            );
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: Do you have any news? :)

Answer (score 1):

Refer:
[Tradingview Simple Moving Average widget configure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253579/tradingview-simple-moving-average-widget-configure/73432483)

Try like this,

You should use the names of the studies in the Insert Study dialog as they are but using lower case letters.

```
  "studies_overrides": {
        "moving average.ma.color": "#2A2E39",
        "moving average.ma.linewidth": 2,
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an overrider object to the widget constructor just like you are passing other parameters such as width, or height:

```
new TradingView.widget({
    overrides: {
        'paneProperties.background': '#2E2E2E',
    }
});
```

This one would change the background, for example.
To know more about overrides just consult the wiki page of the library, on the overrides section :)