# Tradingview Simple Moving Average widget configure

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I am using trading view simple moving average (20,44,100,200) using below code.

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_e2cd6"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSDT/?exchange=BINANCE" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">BTCUSDT Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "autosize": true,
  "symbol": "BINANCE:BTCUSDT",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "withdateranges": true,
  "hide_side_toolbar": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "studies": [
    {
        id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies",
        inputs: {
            length: 20
            }
    },
    {
        id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies",
        inputs: {
            length: 100
            }
    },
    {
        id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies",
        inputs: {
            length: 44
            }
    },
    {
        id: "MASimple@tv-basicstudies",
        inputs: {
            length: 200
            }
    }
  ],
  "container_id": "tradingview_e2cd6"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

However i want to change moving average line color and line width for different average, so i tried with `studies_overrides` function with different inputs but it seems its not working.

Example: I want to change line color to `white` for 20 days moving average so i tried below code

```
"studies_overrides": {
            "moving average.lineStyle.color.0": "#ffffff", //Not working
            "simple moving average.lineStyle.color.0": "#ffffff", //Not working
            "MASimple@tv-basicstudies.lineStyle.color.0": "#ffffff", //Not working
        }, //Same on 'lineWidth: 2' not working
```

any one know how to change color and line width properly?

Ref: https://static.kancloud.cn/isung/tradingview/972246, https://static.kancloud.cn/isung/tradingview/972244

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

You should use the names of the studies in the Insert Study dialog as they are but using lower case letters.

```
  "studies_overrides": {
        "moving average.ma.color": "#2A2E39",
        "moving average.ma.linewidth": 2,
    },
```

[image]